# Why is there no 'www-data' group by default?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

I just tried to install (and then start) Apache2 HTTPD, but was greeted with the error:

```
apache2: bad group name 'www-data'
```

I quickly checked my `/etc/group`, and there is no `www-data` group. I always assumed it exists on Debian by default (or, at least, is created when I install an HTTPD).

So, why does it not exist? If I remember correctly, it usually exists on Debian by default. I guess I could just create it, but I'm wondering if there's a certain intention behind this.

Comment: Sorry, Oliver I don't think this is a real question - I think this is a bug in the Apache install scripts.

Comment: Though how to get Apache installed and running with the www-data group would make a good question. Especially since one of the YouTube videos suggest running it as Pi.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: I don't think you're correct. The `www-data` group exists on **all** my Debian installations. No matter if Apache is installed or not. It's a built-in system group with the id `33`. This group is non-existent on the Raspberry Pi version of Debian.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Okay... So what's the question?

Comment: @BryanDunsmore: The question is why it was removed even though official Debian packages obviously depend on it?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Yes, but we are not here to debate design decisions of an operating system. We are here to answer real questions. Which is why I VTC as _not constructive_.

Comment: So this is unique to the Pi version of Debian?

Comment: @Jivings: At least that's what I'm still assuming. But there are only so many Debian installations I've worked with.

Comment: Seems unlikely they would make this omission unintentionally...

Comment: Closed this question as not constructive due to the fact that reasons for the omission are unlikely to be useful to this site.  A question asking how to fix this problem would be constructive, but as it stands it's difficult to see a benefit to the community.